# Do Heroku Apps have a request timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, timeout, background-process

I'm currently developing a rails application which involves mass sending of emails. In my local server, when I tried sending 500 emails at one shot, it works fine (despite being a little laggy). However, once I've pushed the app onto Heroku and tried sending the 500 emails again, it shows me an application error! I tried looking at the logs and it says there's a request timeout but it works fine on my localhost! How do I solve this error? On a side note, is there a way to push the method to a background process so it wont cause any timeout? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application doesn't send something in 30 seconds then the request is timed out:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#timeouts